# Update of a Dependency Property when variable or field on which it depends on changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

What I need to do is?

I need to make one expression on which dependency property should depends on.

Suppose as per below:

```
Count = dependOne + dependTwo;
```

Here, `Count`  is **Dependency property** and `dependOne` and `dependTwo` are two variables on which dependency property `Count` should Depends on.

Now whenever I change variable `dependOne` or `dependTwo` the dependency property should have to update automatically.

Is it possible? If yes then how?

See the code below

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="DependecnyProperty.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Background="LightGray" Text="{Binding Path=Count}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,102,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,148,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
namespace DependecnyProperty
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            Count = dependOne + dependTwo;
        }

        int dependOne = 0;
        int dependTwo = 0;

        public int Count
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(CountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CountProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Count.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Count", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(12));

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dependOne = dependOne + 2;
            dependTwo = dependTwo + 1;

            //I need to find way ...now here i have changed value of two variable.
            //now it is possible to change Dependency Property
            //Without here setting the value of dependency property
        }


    }
}
```

**EDIT UPDATED CODEBEHIND:**

```
namespace DependecnyProperty
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ViewModel vm;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            vm = new ViewModel();
            //this.DataContext = vm;
            Count = vm.DependOne + vm.DependTwo;
        }


        public int Count
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(CountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CountProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Count.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Count", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(12));

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.DependOne++;
            vm.DependTwo++;
            //I need to find way ...now here i have changed value of two variable.
            //now it is possible to change Dependency Property
            //Without here setting the value of dependency property

        }

        public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public ViewModel()
            {

            }

            private int dependOne;

            public int DependOne
            {
                get
                {
                    return dependOne;
                }
                set 
                { 
                    dependOne = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DependOne");
                }
            }

            private int dependTwo;

            public int DependTwo
            {
                get 
                { 
                    return dependTwo; 
                }
                set 
                { 
                    dependTwo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DependTwo");
                }
            }

            #region --  INotifyPropertyChanged Members  --

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyNameArg)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyNameArg));
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is the best solution for you. One of these ,however, would be that you use Property like:

```
    //field
    private int _dependOne;

    //property
    public int DependOne
    {
        get { return _dependOne; }
        set {
            _dependOne = value;
            Count += value;
        }
    }

    //Finally, use the property instead of the field
    //dependOne = dependOne + 2;
    DependOne += 2;
```

---

**UPDATED:**
The important thing is that you don't update ViewModel properties in Codebehind. Instead, you could call a ViewModel method.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="DependOne" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding Path="DependTwo" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Click="button1_Click">click</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**CODE**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }


    //public int Count
    //{
    //    get { return (int)GetValue(CountProperty); }
    //    set { SetValue(CountProperty, value); }
    //}

    //// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Count.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    //public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
    //    DependencyProperty.Register("Count", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(12));

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.UpdateCount();
    }


}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ViewModel()
    {

    }

    private int dependOne = 0;

    public int DependOne
    {
        get
        {
            return dependOne;
        }
        set
        {
            dependOne = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DependOne");
        }
    }

    private int dependTwo = 0;

    public int DependTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return dependTwo;
        }
        set
        {
            dependTwo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DependTwo");
        }
    }

    #region --  INotifyPropertyChanged Members  --

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyNameArg)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyNameArg));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    internal void UpdateCount()
    {
        DependOne = 3;
        DependTwo = 4;
    }
}

public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dependOne = (int)values[0];
        var dependTwo = (int)values[1];

        return (dependOne + dependTwo).ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's the simple one... As not knowing your actual situation, I just said this, but I think @Merlyn Morgan-Graham is good point. Also, you can consider making the dependOne as `DependecnyProperty` if the dependOne acts on View. Then, use `Value Changed Callback` to update the Count.

Comment: Thanks for answering ..but.. ,,as per the Graham's answer.....where we have to put expression...`Count = dependOne + dependTwo;
`

Comment: the Graham's answer is not this... You should use Binding the Count with the dependOne and dependTwo in XAML.

Comment: @Jung,,using Mltibinding or any other way?/

Comment: Of course, it's need `Multibinding` with `IMultiValueConverter`.

Comment: @jwJung let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1535/discussion-between-aryan-suryawansi-and-jwjung)

Comment: +1; My answer is more or less this, but you posted the complete code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd:

- Put `dependOne` and `dependTwo` in a View Model
- Add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the View Model
- Raise the property changed event when those property's setters got called
- Use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) to bind the dependency property to those two view model properties

Then the setter would automatically get called whenever those properties were updated.

Another advantage of this solution is that you could separate the counter logic from the dependency property logic.  It would be easier to unit test, and possibly easier to reuse in different scenarios.

Comment: @Graham,,,i am confused where to put `Expression`.....`Count = dependOne + dependTwo;`

Comment: @Aryan: You'd put it in a custom `IMultiValueConverter`, to use with a `MultiBinding`.

Comment: I just posted the code, but the origin of the idea is from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A pretty similar approach to the answer by *Merlyn Morgan-Graham*, you can introduce another readonly property called Count in your ViewModel. Raise PropertyChanged("Count") whenever DependOne or DependTwo changes, then you can do a OneWay binding against Count

```
private int m_dependOne;
public int DependOne
{
    get { return m_dependOne; }
    set
    {
        m_dependOne = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DependOne");
        OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    }
}

private int m_dependTwo;
public int DependTwo
{
    get { return m_dependTwo; }
    set
    {
        m_dependTwo = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DependTwo");
        OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    }
}

public int Count
{
    get
    {
        return m_dependOne + m_dependTwo;
    }
}
```

Then binding is just as simple as

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```